# Enable native MacOS Mojave Dark Theme PySide2/Python apps on QT 5.12

Tags: python, macos, themes, qt5, pyside2

I would like to know to enable the native MacOS Mojave Dark Theme (and if could be multiplatform win/linux, the better) which is supposed to be available from QT 5.12 (which I guess, it should be available in PySide2).

By default, the apps are still the same way, I don't know what to do to enable it.

Thanks!!

P.S.: using python 2.7.10 (and the solution of pyinstaler works!!, but not running python directly)

Comment: I tried with QDarkStyleSheet, and it looks horrible, no native at all, totally blue-ish...

Comment: I can't believe that no one knows... :(

Comment: It looks like a problem with PySide2? https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-876

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how are you running your application.  As a module

```
python -m application
or
python application.py
```

For me with python 3.7.3 installed with homebrew just works.

But if you are using pyinstaller in the spec file in the section app = BUNDLE add this

```
info_plist={
   'NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance': 'No'
},
```

App bundles I create with this option work in Dark Mode or Light Mode the application changes the interface to use the appropriate one.

Comment: Nice, it works in PyInstaller, which is really good.
I have never used with the -m option... so I use python application.py
Could you please let me know how to run a python with the mojave dark theme?
If you can, I will mark the solution as solved!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS applications to support dark mode, they either need to be built against the macOS 10.14 or later SDK, or to include the `'NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance': 'No'` property mentioned by @efrain.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app for further details.

To get dark mode when running your app directly with Python, you'll need to ensure your Python binary was built against macOS 10.4 or later. The easiest way to do this is probably to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your Python installation.

Comment: Can you set the minimum deployment target while building python on macOS using pyenv?