# Freezing app with pyinstaller or fbs changes default color scheme of pyside2 app

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside2, fbs

MacOS
PySide2 5.12.3

I built a GUI using fbs and pyside2.  Everything works fine when issuing `fbs run`, but when I freeze the app `fbs freeze` and launch the target/dist version the app color scheme is reversed.

I confirmed it with the [fbs-tutorial](https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial) app.  It does the same thing.  Starts as a dark color scheme, but after freezing, the color scheme is light.

Any text or elements that I have specifically set the css color for are not affected.

I'm running python 3.7 which isn't officially supported by fbs yet, so I tried just using pyinstaller to freeze the app.  It does the same thing.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**:
I decided to install python 3.6 and run the tutorial app from there.  The default color scheme now appears to be the light version.  So whether I run the working or the frozen app they are both light themed.  Only when switching to python 3.7 (everthing else is the same) does the default color scheme change to dark.  Why would python version be affecting the default color scheme for a PySide2 app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable native MacOS Mojave Dark Theme PySide2/Python apps on QT 5.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106717/enable-native-macos-mojave-dark-theme-pyside2-python-apps-on-qt-5-12)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56285365/4868652).

Essentially, on MacOS I had to bundle an Info.plist file with my application that had the following entry:

```
    <key>NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance</key>
    <string>False</string>
```

Comment: When I made this change to the plist file of the app, it actually turned dark! But unfortunately all widgets disappeared as well, leaving only a blank window... Any ideas?